# Get rid of = in Firebase notification message

Tags: java, android, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

When i send a notification to another device using **Firebase** an `=` sign appears in the notification data. Is there any way to get rid of this?

```
public void sendnotification(String username,long user_unique){


        try {
                    Sender sender = new FCMSender(fcmKey);

                    Message message = new Message.Builder()
                            .collapseKey(username)
                            .timeToLive(3)
                            .delayWhileIdle(true)

                            .addData(username, "Request to book ticket")
                            .build();

                    String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();


                    System.out.println("Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);
                    Result result = sender.send(message,
                           iid, 1);

                    System.out.println("Result: " + result.toString());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }



    }
```

This will appear in the device receiving the notification as `User=Request to book ticket`. I want to get rid of this '=' sign in between

Comment: `=` sign is in the username , try to debug username , or you can do **username.replaceAll("=","");** in the `addData()` method

Comment: The username is actually a name so the notification appears as Bert=Request to book ticket. Username has only string charatcters. There is no = sign anywhere in the username

Comment: What is the data printout code in another app?

Comment: Console output is:   V/fullmsg:  Caroline= Request to book ticket.